# Implement a interface of a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven

I have a maven project that creates a CRUD webservice using REST.
If I use this:

```
@GET
@Path("/getallfornecedores")
@Produces("application/json;")
public Fornecedor getAllFornecedores(){
    Fornecedor f = new Fornecedor();
    f.setName("Bruno");
    return f;
}
```

My code works fine. But I want to use a interface implementation, so I did this:

```
private ICrud crud;

@GET
@Path("/getallfornecedores")
@Produces("application/json;")
public Fornecedor getAllFornecedores(){
    return crud.getAllFornecedores();
}
```

The interface:

```
public interface ICrud {
    public Fornecedor getAllFornecedores();
}
```

And the implementation:

```
public class Crud implements ICrud{ 
    public Fornecedor getAllFornecedores(){
        Fornecedor fornecedor = new Fornecedor();
        fornecedor.setId(1);
        fornecedor.setName("Bruno");
        fornecedor.setEmail("bruno.camargo_@outlook.com");
        fornecedor.setComment("OK");

        return fornecedor;
    }
}
```

But when I do this, I got the following error:

```
  The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
  java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Why is this happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: did icrud instance initated ? icrud = new Crud() and also post all exception log

Comment: Yes that was it! Thank you!!

Comment: glad to help...so I will post as a answer here someone looking for same problem can be help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create icrud object to pass

try this

```
public interface ICrud {
    public Fornecedor getAllFornecedores();
}

public class Crud implements ICrud{ 
    public Fornecedor getAllFornecedores(){
        Fornecedor fornecedor = new Fornecedor();
        fornecedor.setId(1);
        fornecedor.setName("Bruno");
        fornecedor.setEmail("bruno.camargo_@outlook.com");
        fornecedor.setComment("OK");

        return fornecedor;
    }
}

public class Controller { 


private ICrud crud = new Crud();


@GET
@Path("/getallfornecedores")
@Produces("application/json;")
public Fornecedor getAllFornecedores(){
    return crud.getAllFornecedores();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mithat konuk. The resolution was instantiate the interface with the implementation.